# Insert nested object in multiple tables using Room

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I have a Json similar to below format:

```
{
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "first": "Axel",
        "last": "Raab"
      }
}
```

I want to create 2 tables, say Person and Name and store this data in these 2 tables.
My Entity classes look like these:

```
@Entity
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var pid: Int,

    @SerializedName("gender")
    var gender: String?,

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Ignore
    var name: Name?,
) 

@Entity(indices = [Index("pId")],
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Person::class,
        parentColumns = ["pid"],
        childColumns = ["pId"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
data class Name(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val mId: Int,

    @SerializedName("first")
    var first: String?,

    @SerializedName("last")
    var last: String?,

    var pId: Int
)
```

I have created corresponding Daos but unable to identify a way where I can write a transaction that would store this data into 2 tables and relate then using provided ids.
I have gone through many solutions that would either use @Embedded or @Relation or TypeConverter approaches but either they do not fit  my use case or the solution is about querying the data and not how to save or insert.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Embedded`
e.g

```
public class Coordinates {
       double latitude;
       double longitude;
   }
   public class Address {
       String street;
       @Embedded
       Coordinates coordinates;
   }
```

Insert example in your `DAO`

```
@Insert
fun insert(item: Coordinates)
```

you can pass `Coordinates` instance variable in your insert function

```
Address("your street", Coordinates(your_lat,your_lng))
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. But if I am not wrong, @Embedded is used to create a flat structure which is it would populate Coordinates columns inside Address table which isn't my requirement currently. I would like a separate Address table and Coordinate table wherein Address table primary key is a foreign key inside Coordinate table. Hope this further makes my requirement more clear.